# How can I determine the version number of my Ubuntu One for Windows client?

Tags: ubuntu-one-windows

I cannot find an "About..." link or similar in the release version of Ubuntu One for Windows. How can I tell what version number of the client I have currently installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open a terminal and type `dpkg -l | grep ubuntuone-client`... just kidding.

Navigate to the Windows Control Panel and click the item that is—in various versions—referred to as "Add/Remove Programs" or "Uninstall a Program". You will find a list of installed software and metadata about it, including the version number:

On some versions of XP you might need to click the "Click here for support information" link for the Ubuntu One entry to reveal the version number.

[image: Picture of the list of installed software, with Ubuntu One highlighted]

Comment: Ah! Didn't even occur to me to try looking in there. I'm still on 1.0-beta3, apparently...going to have to upgrade. Thanks!